# How can I tell what mode my pub transformer is running in?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am writing a pub transformer for Dart. I'd like the transformer to know what mode pub is run in (debug or other). Can the Transformer tell what mode it's running in? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Transformers can have different constructors. One of the constructors can take a `BarbackSettings` objects, which contains the mode.

For example:

```dart
class DartToJsScriptRewriter extends Transformer {
  bool releaseMode = false;

  DartToJsScriptRewriter.asPlugin(BarbackSettings settings)
      : releaseMode = (settings.mode == BarbackMode.RELEASE);
```